# file transfer using NetworkCredential

Tags: c#

While transferring the file from one machine to another machine using C#.Net without socket code is as follows:

```
string filePath = "C:\\tags.txt";
try
{
    WebClient client = new WebClient();
    string uName = "myUserName", password ="myPassword";
    NetworkCredential nc = new NetworkCredential(uName, password); 
    Uri addy = new Uri("\\192.168.1.28\\Files\\ tags.txt");
    client.Credentials = nc;
    byte[] arrReturn = client.UploadFile(addy, filePath);
    Console.WriteLine(arrReturn.ToString());
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
}
```

"192.168.1.28\Files\ tags.txt"-> this is another machine IP and location 
when I debug the error occured in the Uri Class.

Error is-> `Invalid URI: The format of the URI could not be determined.`

Here I could send the file to target machine if the location is in share.
Ii need to send a file to the corresponding location even if the folder is not shared.

Is the above code correct code?

Comment: have you tried putting file:/// on the start of the upload location?

Comment: In your code, I see a space before tags.txt. Can you try removing it?
Like this:
`Uri addy = new Uri("\\192.168.1.28\\Files\\tags.txt");`

Answer (score 0):

have you tried something like `File.Copy()`? I'm not sure if File.Copy uses Windows credentials. if it does then this is the easiest way to transfer files between two computers.

`client.UploadFile()` can also use two string parameters instead of an URI and a string; you could try sending the URI via a string.

where you wrote the Uri you need to put 4 slashes in front of the ip

```
//This is unrelated
//System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(arrReturn)
```